# error in a Function that tries to remove NAs to calculate a value

Tags: r

I have the following function:

```
Fisher.test <- function(p) {
   Xsq <- -2*sum(log(p), na.rm=TRUE)
   p.val <- 1-pchisq(Xsq, df = 2*length(p))
   return(p.val)
}
```

I was guessing that command `na.rm=TRUE` was dealing with `NA` in my data. However, when I test the function with simple values the behaviour is not the expected. For example:

```
Fisher.test(c(0.1,0.4,0.1,NA))
[1] 0.199279


Fisher.test(c(0.1,0.4,0.1))
[1] 0.08705891
```

Why in the first option I do not get the same result as in the second one? The `na.rm=TRUE` should remove the `NA`??

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the lengths of those two vectors are different. If you just wanted to filter out `NA`s you could use `sum(!is.na(p))` instead of `length(p)`, but since `log` can produce a `NaN` for negative values, which will also get filtered out by your `sum`, I'd use `sum(p >= 0, na.rm = T)` instead (or just `sum(!is.na(log(p)))` to let `R` figure out the details itself):

```
Fisher.test <- function(p) {
   Xsq <- -2*sum(log(p), na.rm=TRUE)
   p.val <- 1-pchisq(Xsq, df = 2*sum(p >= 0, na.rm = T))
   return(p.val)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @eddi, in case that there is no negative values in my data, which approach in terms of "speed" do you would use? `sum(!is.na(p))` or `sum(p >= 0, na.rm = T)`?

Comment: `sum(!is.na(p))` is a little faster; check out the `microbenchmark` package to easily check these sorts of things